# Python Tklinter Button calling a function from another class

Tags: python, class

I have defined a Button with Tklinter

```
class ventanapp(Tk):

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()
        self.entry = Entry(self)
        msg = Message(text=' SSH - Ingresar IP ->')
        self.entry.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='EW')
        button = Button(self,text=u"realizar la conexion",command=ssh.crear_ssh())
        button.grid(column=1,row=0)
```

But when i call the `command=ssh.crear_ssh()` from Another Class

```
class ssh():
    def crear_ssh():
        print('PONER ACA EL CODIGO DE LA CONEXION')`
```

I receive the error : "global name 'ssh' is not defined"

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: what are you importing? is `ssh()` in the same file? Also, im pretty sure you need a `self` inside of the arguments for `crear_ssh(self)`

Comment: Did it with Self on crear_ssh but still same error! And yes, all of this is on the same file!

Comment: try making the `ssh()` object first... like in the line above do `someVar = ssh()`, and then change the part where it says `command=ssh.crear_ssh()` to `command=someVar.crear_ssh()` ( also try it without the `()` because i think Tkinter already adds those in when doing a command

Comment: TehTis, this has solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented the solution was to create a variable of the class SSH should be created before the class definition of ventana.

ssh = ssh()
button = Button(self,text=u"realizar la conexion",command=lambda: ssh.crear_ssh())

Many thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure how your project is laid out, but:

```
class ventanapp(Tk):

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()
        self.entry = Entry(self)
        msg = Message(text=' SSH - Ingresar IP ->')
        self.entry.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='EW')
        #note the lambda below, so the method doesn't run until the button is clicked
        button = Button(self,text=u"realizar la conexion",command=lambda: ssh.crear_ssh)
        button.grid(column=1,row=0)
```

Elsewhere in the same file:

```
class ssh():
    def crear_ssh(self): #added 'self' to the args
        print('PONER ACA EL CODIGO DE LA CONEXION')`
```

Comment: GREAT tip, just added button = Button(self,text=u"realizar la conexion",command= lambda: ssh.crear_ssh()), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The order in wich all variables are created are very important!

command=ssh.crear_ssh()

Should be first !

Regards